# BackgroundWorker UI and Progress issues

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

So I've been fiddling with this for a while and I don't know if I'm not understanding how the BackgroundWorker works and/or I'm using it wrong or if I'm missing something.

Basically what I'm trying to do is call a BackgroundWorker from a DragDrop function where the user can drop a set of images into the form. The BackgroundWorder then copies the images to a temp location thumbnails are pulled and turned into PictureBoxes and the PictureBoxes are added to a collection. Once the BackgroundWorker is completed the function runs to add all the picture boxes to the form.

All of this is working properly except the progress. The progress function doesn't like to fire until near the end (after almost all the pictures have been copied) during this time the UI is locked (which I'm sure is why the progress function isn't firing) I just can't figure out why the UI is locking.

I've stepped through the code and the ReportProgress method is being called ever loop but the ProgressReported function isn't called until near the end.

HELP! LOL

this is the ControlClass for my copying and creating thumbnails

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO

Namespace ThumbnailViewer

    Public Class ThumbnailControl
        Inherits FlowLayoutPanel

        Private ImageExtensions As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {".JPG", ".JPE", ".BMP", ".GIF", ".PNG"}
        Private tempStoragePath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\tempPhotos"
        Private WithEvents bkWPhotos As New BackgroundWorker
        Public Property iThumbList As List(Of PictureBox)
        Public Property sImageList As List(Of String(,))
        Private PopupPrg As PopUpProgress.PopUpProgressControl

        Public Sub New()
            Me.AutoScroll = True
            Me.AllowDrop = True
            Me.DoubleBuffered = True
            iThumbList = New List(Of PictureBox)()
            sImageList = New List(Of String(,))()
            AddHandler Me.DragDrop, AddressOf ThumbnailViewerControl_DragDrop
            AddHandler Me.DragEnter, AddressOf ThumbnailViewerControl_DragEnter
            If Not Directory.Exists(tempStoragePath) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(tempStoragePath)
            bkWPhotos.WorkerReportsProgress = True
            bkWPhotos.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        End Sub

        Public Sub BackGroundWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bkWPhotos.DoWork
            AddImage(e.Argument)
        End Sub

        Public Sub BackGroundWorkder_Progress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bkWPhotos.ProgressChanged
            PopupPrg.SetProgress(e.ProgressPercentage)
        End Sub

        Public Sub BackGroundWorker_Complete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bkWPhotos.RunWorkerCompleted
            For Each i As PictureBox In iThumbList
                Me.Controls.Add(i)
            Next
            PopupPrg.Destory()
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End Sub

        Public Sub AddImage(ByVal files As String())
            Dim fImage As Image

            Dim prg As Integer = 0
            For Each f As String In files
                If ImageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToUpperInvariant()) Then
                    bkWPhotos.ReportProgress(prg)
                    fImage = Image.FromFile(f)
                    File.Copy(f, tempStoragePath & "\" & Path.GetFileName(f), True)
                    sImageList.Add({{tempStoragePath & "\" & Path.GetFileName(f), fImage.Size.Width, fImage.Size.Height}})
                    Dim t As PictureBox = MakeThumbnail(fImage)
                    prg = prg + 1
                    GC.GetTotalMemory(True)
                End If
            Next
        End Sub

        Public Function MakeThumbnail(ByVal inImage As Image) As PictureBox
            Dim thumb As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
            thumb.Size = ScaleImage(inImage.Size, 200)
            thumb.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            thumb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            AddHandler thumb.MouseEnter, AddressOf thumb_MouseEnter
            AddHandler thumb.MouseLeave, AddressOf thumb_MouseLeave
            AddHandler thumb.DoubleClick, AddressOf thumb_DoubleClick
            thumb.Image = inImage.GetThumbnailImage(thumb.Width - 2, thumb.Height - 2, Nothing, New IntPtr())
            iThumbList.Add(thumb)
            Return thumb
        End Function

        Private Sub thumb_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim previewForm As Form = New Form()
            Dim index As Integer = Me.Controls.GetChildIndex(CType(sender, PictureBox))
            Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(sImageList(index)(0, 0))
            previewForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow
            previewForm.MinimizeBox = False
            previewForm.Size = ScaleImage(img.Size, Screen.GetWorkingArea(Me).Height / 4 * 3)
            previewForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
            Dim view As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
            view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            view.Image = Image.FromFile(sImageList(index)(0, 0))
            view.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            previewForm.Controls.Add(view)
            previewForm.ShowDialog()
        End Sub

        Private Sub thumb_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            CType(sender, PictureBox).Invalidate()
        End Sub

        Private Sub thumb_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim rc = (CType(sender, PictureBox)).ClientRectangle
            rc.Inflate(-2, -2)
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder((CType(sender, PictureBox)).CreateGraphics(), (CType(sender, PictureBox)).ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D((CType(sender, PictureBox)).CreateGraphics(), rc, Border3DStyle.Bump)
        End Sub

        Private Sub ThumbnailViewerControl_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
            If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy Else e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End Sub

        Private Sub ThumbnailViewerControl_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
            If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
                Dim files As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
                PopupPrg = New PopUpProgress.PopUpProgressControl(Me, files.Count)
                bkWPhotos.RunWorkerAsync(files)
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Function ScaleImage(ByVal oldImage As Size, ByVal TargetHeight As Integer) As Size
            Dim NewHeight As Integer = TargetHeight
            Dim NewWidth As Integer = NewHeight / oldImage.Height * oldImage.Width
            NewHeight = NewWidth / oldImage.Width * oldImage.Height
            Return New Size(NewWidth, NewHeight)
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: DO NOT do ANYTHING related to the UI in the `DoWork` event handler or any method called from the `DoWork` event handler. By all means do all your image manipulation in the `DoWork` event handler but a `PictureBox` is a control. Is a control not part of the UI? Get all your `Image` objects in a list and then pass that list to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler via the `e.Result` property. There you can create the `PictureBox` controls and load the `Image` objects into them. Alternatively, call `ReportProgress` and create one `PictureBox` at a time in the `ProgressChanged` event handler.

Comment: I'm only generating a list of picture boxes. I don't add them to the gui until the worker completes. Does that still execute on the gui thread? I'm not invoking the picture box and I'm not getting a permission error. So yes it is a control but it's not part of the ui till the end.

Comment: When jmcilhinney said _ANYTHING_ he really meant it. It actually does include instantiating controls even if you're not adding them. This is because at the very moment that you instantiate anything that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` it is automatically bound _to the current thread_, meaning even if you don't get a cross-thread exception right away you now have a control on the UI thread that is bound to a background thread.

Comment: @VisualVincent if what your saying is true wouldn't that be considered a bug? Shouldn't any cross-threading operations be blocked if not specifically invoked? Serious question because backgroundworkers are still fairly new for me. I understand the basic concept of throwing the work on a new thread to be processed along side, but if initiating a new control structure invokes the UI thread without being requested to that seems like a flaw to me.

Comment: No, it isn't a bug. This is simply how controls work. Upon instantiation the control is _**tied to the current thread**_ (it doesn't invoke the UI thread). It does this for synchronization purposes, so that the runtime knows which thread it was created on. For instance, if you read the [**documentation for `Control.Invoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that it: _"Executes the specified delegate **on the thread** that owns the control's underlying window handle."_

Answer (score 1):

.... FacePalm.. I figured it out. Apparently during my testing (before I decided to use this control and a background worker, I had added another drag drop function in another area of my code that was being called first. It was taking all the dragged images and turning them into Image data types. The rest of the function was commented out which is why I didn't notice it before because I was only stepping though the classes functions not the functions in the main UI. but it makes perfect sense now, the backgroundworker and the UI function were kicking off at the same time but while the UI thread was processing the Image data typing the report progress calls were stacking up.

After removing that secondary function it works exactly as it should, UI remains fully functional Images and PictureBoxes are processed in the background and the Progressbar updates properly and remains functional as well.